# RMySQL: Closing a connection without a handle

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I am experimenting with [RMySQL](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/index.html), and have accidentally created a connection without a handle.

```
dbConnect(MySQL(), user = "foo", password = "bar")
connLocalDB = dbConnect(MySQL(), user = "foo", password = "bar")
```

Note that the return of the first call is not assigned to anything. Now, when I do a `dbListConnections(MySQL())` I see two connections:

```
> dbListConnections(MySQL())
[[1]]
<MySQLConnection:0,0>

[[2]]
<MySQLConnection:0,1>
```

I then tried this:

```
> dbDisconnect(dbListConnections(MySQL())[[1]])
[1] TRUE
```

but, then, I got this:

```
> dbListConnections(MySQL())
[[1]]
Error in .local(dbObj, ...) : 
  internal error in RS_DBI_getConnection: corrupt connection handle
```

How to safely terminate a connection that is not assigned a handle?

Comment: You won't need to worry about this in the next version (i.e. the version on github)

Comment: @hadley Strangest thing. Just updated, and it now gives me `> dbListConnections(MySQL())                                                     # list the open connections

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbListConnections’ for signature ‘"MySQLDriver"’
`

Comment: @hadley All kinds of other errors popping up, including unable to perform passwordless login using a configuration file in the home directory.

Comment: @hadley Following up to see if you can help diagnose these errors with the dev version of the package.

Comment: File bugs at github please. `dbListConnections()` is no longer implemented because it's not needed.

Comment: @hadley Thanks. The dev version makes too many breaking changes, and I think that I will revert to the version on CRAN for now. I assume there isn't a way to handle this (pun not intended) within that version?

Comment: Well it would be useful to here what those breaking changes are...

Comment: @hadley I will happily oblige on the RMySQL & DBI issues page. Mind you, I consider API changes without prior deprecation warnings breaking changes.

Answer (score 1):

Generally for creating a connection, getting the data of a query and then closing the connection I use the following function:

```
getDataSql <- function( query ) {
  con = dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname  =  "dbname", host = "host", user = "username", password = "pasword", port = "port")
  result <- dbGetQuery(con, query)
  dbDisconnect(con)
  result
}
```